# Derivation of Double (Brown) Exponential Smoothing

Tags: time-series

I am learning the double (Brown) exponential smoothing. Comparing to the simple exponential smoothing, the Brown exponential smoothing smooths the output sequence $Y_t$ twice, such that
\begin{align}
S^{(1)}_t &= \alpha Y_t + (1-\alpha)S^{(1)}_{t-1}\\
S^{(2)}_t &= \alpha S^{(1)}_t + (1-\alpha)S^{(2)}_{t-1}
\end{align}
I tried to derive its equivalent smoothing equations via level and trend functions
\begin{align}
L_t & = 2S^{(1)}_t - S^{(2)}_t\\
T_t &= \alpha \left(S^{(1)}_t - S^{(1)}_{t-1}\right) + (1-\alpha)T_{t-1}
\end{align}
where $Y_{t+1} = L_t + T_t + e_{t+1} = S^{(1)}_t + \frac{1}{\alpha} T_t + e_{t+1}$.

But I failed, can anyone help me to derive smoothing equations from the double exponential smoothing? many thanks!